# After installing new version of VS 2019 16.9.1 I am unable to work with SSIS and save Script Task

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

After installing new version of VS 2019 16.9.1, I am unable to work with SSIS and save Script Task.

I got an error: "Script contained in the package have compilation errors, The Binary Code for the Script is Not Found"

I tried everything like:

- Repair VS
- Reinstall Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices

Those did not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try pressing compile in the code window?

Comment: Do any of these help: https://coderwall.com/p/dfcrkq/ssis-error-the-binary-code-for-the-script-is-not-found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528349/the-binary-code-for-the-script-is-not-found

Comment: Yes I got an error : Could not find a part of the path

Comment: Nick.McDermaid Yes I got an error : Could not find a part of the path

Comment: I googled both those errors and found this page https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview which says  _There is a regression in VS 2019 16.9 that will cause script task/component not work properly when editing script. VSTA team has released a new version to work around this issue. Please download the latest version of VSTA 2019 here and manually install it to work around the issue._

Comment: If it works please post back

Comment: Sorry it's didn't helped I get the same error after saving and closing the Script Task

Comment: hmm I don't think I can help much further. I do think that's the key though - you might have to fully uninstall first. Unfortunately SSIS editor (SSDT) is a terribly buggy product. When it's working, don't mess with it

Comment: Already tried this 1. repair of vs 2. reinstall SSDT Agree its a really terribly buggy product!

Answer (score 0):

When I face this problem, I downgrade to lower version like 16.8.2 and it is now work.

Comment: Actually I am already found the URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history

Answer (score 0):

I had received the answer from Microsoft:
There is a regression in VS 16.9. VSTA team has released a new version to work around this issue. Please download and install latest version of VSTA 2019 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58317, or you can wait for our next Hotfix release which will be released soon.